# yii2 yii\\db\\ActiveQuery::with() not working

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to retrieve all categories that has active merchants

```
      $query = category::find()::with([
         'merchants' => function ($query) {
            $query->andWhere(['status' => Merchant::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
         }
        ]);
```

but I got this error:

> Using $this when not in object context

how can I solve this

Comment: It should be `category::find()->with()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$query = category::find()::with()` should be `$query = category::find()->with()`

```
 $query = category::find()
    ->with([
        'merchants' => function ($query) {
            $query->andWhere(['status' => Merchant::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
         }
    ]);
```